# Displaying a maximum of n elements, with an indication if there are more, using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a stylesheet for RSS feed parsing.  One challenge is that I'd prefer presenting just a summary of the article if it happens to be long and doesn't include <cut> tags.  Say, the first 6 child elements of the post (allowing for metadata plus 2-3 paragraphs of content).

I've just run across the ':nth-child' and ':nth-of-class' pseudo selectors, and they address the first part of my goal.  However I'm stumped in finding a way (using just CSS) to indicate that there's additional content.

[A fiddle with some sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/zbkc7/) (also below).

It succeeds in presenting just the first 3 elements of the list, but fails to display the "There's more you're not seeing" text (given as a ":before" pseudo element).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 25 March 2009), see www.w3.org">
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
    li { background-color: #f0f0ff; display: none; }
    li:nth-of-type(-n+3) { background-color: #fff0f0; display: list-item; }
    li:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "There's more you're not seeing";
      display: block }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<p>The first three items on this list should be a different color.</p>

<ol>
  <li>A list item.</li>
  <li>A list item.</li>
  <li>A list item.</li>
  <li>A list item.</li>
  <li>A list item.</li>
  <li>A list item.</li>
  <li>A list item.</li>
  <li>A list item.</li>
  <li>A list item.</li>
  <li>A list item.</li>
  <li>A list item.</li>
</ol>


</body>
</html>
```

Related:  the :nth-foo pseudo elements don't seem to work when grouped below other elements.

**Update:** Nevermind.  I'm not nesting elements, these are peers.

If I duplicate the list above under two paragraphs, one p.foo and one p.bar, where the nth-of-type properties are restricted to .foo only, I don't see the expected results -- *all* content matches the default state.

Style:

```
    .foo li:nth-child(n+5) { 
        background-color: #f0f0ff; 
        /* display: none; */ 
    }

    li { background-color: #fff0f0; }

    .foo li:nth-child(4):before {   
        content: "There's more you're not seeing";
        display: block;
```

HTML:

```
<p class="foo">The first three items on this list should be a different color.</p>

<ol>
    <li>A list item.</li>
    <li>A list item.</li>
    <li>A list item.</li>
    <li>A list item.</li>
    <li>A list item.</li>
    <li>A list item.</li>
    <li>A list item.</li>
    <li>A list item.</li>
    <li>A list item.</li>
    <li>A list item.</li>
    <li>A list item.</li>
</ol>

<p class="bar">All items on this list should be the same color.</p>

<ol>
    <li>A list item.</li>
    <li>A list item.</li>
    <li>A list item.</li>
    <li>A list item.</li>
    <li>A list item.</li>
    <li>A list item.</li>
    <li>A list item.</li>
    <li>A list item.</li>
    <li>A list item.</li>
    <li>A list item.</li>
    <li>A list item.</li>
</ol>
```

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/E8LGp/

---

**But:** There's still the challenge of trying to limit the number of entities where each occurs as a sub-element of a peer.  See this post:  http://james-kunstler-feed.dreamwidth.org/912.html

The images appear as:

```
<div class="entry-content">
  <p>
    <a>
      <img>
    </a>
   <p>
  <p>
    <a>
      <img>
    </a>
   <p>
  <p>
    <a>
      <img>
    </a>
   <p>
  <p>
    <a>
      <img>
    </a>
   <p>
 </div>
```

So that while the

elements are nth-of-type peers, each of the images is a singleton within its div > p > a > img hierarchy.

I don't suppose there's some handy way of being able to display one and only one image per feed.  Again, in CSS.

Comment: If you are trying to show only the image inside the first p, and hide the images inside the following p, you could use `.entry-content > p ~ p > a > img { display: none; }`. The tilde in `p ~ p` means "general sibling selector" (http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector), selecting all p after the first p and then, hiding the images inside these p's

Comment: Hrm.  Now that _might_ get me to where I want to go.  I didn't know the ~ selector.